# Read only Textbox in ASP.net MVC View

Tags: asp.net-mvc

How to set the readonly attribute to HTML Textbox helper class.

```
<%= Html.TextBox("Email", "abc@example.com", new { @class = "required email" } )%>
```

Appreciate your response

Answer (score 67, accepted):

```
<%= Html.TextBox("Email", "abc@example.com", new { @class = "required email", @readonly="readonly" }) %>
```

Comment: Is this solution supposed to be used cross browser?

Answer (score 6):

```
<%= Html.TextBox("Email", "abc@example.com", new { @class = "required email", @readonly = "readonly" } )%>
```

Answer (score 3):

For better performance, use the following :

ASPX:

```
<%= Html.TextBox("Email", ew Dictionary<string, object> { {"class","required email"}, {"readonly","readonly"} }  %>
```

Razor:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Email, new Dictionary<string, object> { { "class", "required email" }, {"readonly","readonly"} })
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<%= Html.TextBox("Email", "abc@example.com", new { @class = "required email", readonly="true" } )%>
```

Comment: @ symbol bypasses the reserved word.

Answer (score 2):

```
<%= Html.TextBox("Email", "abc@example.com", new { @class = "required email", @readonly="readonly" } )%>
```

@ symbol bypasses the reserved word.

Answer (score 2):

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Description, new { htmlAttributes = new { @readonly = "readonly" } })
```

works for me